# Is there a way to make Maps and Current Location load faster in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-maps, currentlocation

I have 4 Map Screens in a Stack Manager that lets my users see their current location as they complete tasks. After they complete a task, it sends them to the next maps screen, until that task is complete. There is sometimes a significant amount of lag (10 seconds) from one maps screen to another. While the app is reloading their current location, I have implemented an ActivityIndicator that will run until the function mounts. The function then unmounts when they navigate away and triggers a mounting for the next page where it loads their current location, and repeat. Is there a way to speed up this process and make the maps load faster?

Edit: Up to this point, I have turned off trackViewChanges. I am currently using an icon, and not an image for my custom marker. I tried running in development mode to see if it would run faster (based on some reports that it would) but it did not effect its render ability.

Edit 2: Here is some of the code I use to generate the user's current location.

```
function Screen({navigation}) { 
    const [user_latitude, setUserLatitude] = useState(0)
    const [user_longitude, setUserLongitude] = useState(0)
    const [position_error, setPositionError] = useState(null)
    const [ isLoading, setIsLoading ] = useState(true)
    const [ location, setLocation ] = useState(null);

  const renderLoading = () =>  {
        if (isLoading) {
            return (
            <View style = {{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#d3d3d3', height: height*0.75, width: width}}>
            <ActivityIndicator
            color = 'black'
            size = 'large'
            animated = {false}
          />
          <Text style = { styles.text }>{i18n.t('')}</Text>
          </View>
            );
        }else {
            return null;
        }
    }

useFocusEffect( 
      React.useCallback(()=> {

      let isActive = true;

      const fetchGeoPosition = () => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => { 
          if (isActive){
          setUserLatitude(position.coords.latitude);
          setUserLongitude(position.coords.longitude);
          setPositionError(null);
          console.log('Location Accessed')
        } 
        setIsLoading(false)

      }, 

      error => isActive && setPositionError(error.message),
      {enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 0, maximumAge: 1000} 
      ); 
    }
    const permission_get = async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android' && !Constants.isDevice) {
        setErrorMsg(
          'Oops, this will not work on Snack in an Android emulator. Try it on your device!'
        );
        return;
      }
      let { status } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        setErrorMsg('Permission to access location was denied');
        console.log('Not permitted')
        return;
      }

      let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(location);
      console.log('Permitted')
    }

    permission_get()
    fetchGeoPosition()

      return () =>{
        isActive = false
        console.log('Location Severed')
    }


        }, 
      [],
       ),
    )



  if (!exercise.trim()){
    return;
  }
  Alert.alert(
    (i18n.t('')),
    (i18n.t('')),
    [
    {
      text: (i18n.t('')),
      onPress: () => navigation.navigate('Screen2')
    },

    {
      text: (i18n.t('')),
     
    }]
    )
}


  return(
      <View style = {styles.container}>

      <View style = {styles.header}>
       <MapView
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        style={styles.map}
        region= {{
        latitude: user_latitude,
        longitude: user_longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0451,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0451
      }}>
      
        <Marker 
        coordinate={ 

          {latitude: user_latitude,
           longitude: user_longitude,
           error: position_error,
         }}
         
        >
        </Marker>
      </MapView>

      <View style = { styles.blank }>
      
      <View style = {{flex:1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
      {(renderLoading())}
      </View>

    </View>
    </View> 
      </View> 
  )
}

export {Screen};

const {height}= Dimensions.get("screen");
const { width } = Dimensions.get("screen")


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'column',
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
    },


  
});
```

Comment: _"Is there a way to speed up this process and make the maps load faster"_ - assume there is. Have a go, and then come back if you run into trouble.

Comment: I should have elaborated on everything I have already tried, don't worry, this was not my first stopping place. I'll update my post with everything I have already tried.

Comment: That genuinely will help a lot.

Comment: Edited my original post. My apologies for not providing it in the first place. I suppose I was more curious if having multiple map screens in a stack was the best way to go about it. My only thought now is to have my server load the screen ahead of time, or not let the user navigate until the next page is loaded; but these would be less than ideal.

Comment: Any update, or do you need more info?

Comment: Providing a [mcve] would be most useful. It’s hard to optimise someone else’s code without seeing it.

Comment: I have uploaded some of my code. This code is used on every maps screen, so as the user completes tasks on one screen, the same code will run in the next screen. I hope this is enough.

Comment: Is this minimally reproducible?